# confused about java looping

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I just started learning programming and java is my first language. I've come across an exercise involving for loop, I'd like to know how the result is found:

```
int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    if(i == 3){ 
        result += 10;
    }
    else{
        result += i;
    }
}
System.out.println(result);
```

the output is: 17

I know this is a silly basic question but I really need to understand how the result is 17.

Comment: The program will add every index, except 3. since `1+2+3+4 = 10`, and we have this `if (i ==3) result += 10`, it's 17. In other words, `instead of adding 3, it will add 10, otherwise it will just sum the indices`.

Comment: What other result did you expect? Why?

Comment: I didn't understand how 17 was found

Comment: In case you still don't understand, step it with a debugger. That will explain what's going on.

Comment: Which part is not clear? When you execute it in your head (or using paper and pencil) what result you are getting? What is your though process (it is hard to correct something if we don't see it)?

Comment: This is a *great* opportunity to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger.  You can use one to step through the code, line by line, as it executes and observe the behaviors of each line of code and how it affects the values of the variables.  When you do this, which specific line of code does something you didn't expect?  What did you expect?  Why?

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. Everything seems so difficult and confusing when you are a beginner. I appreciated your answers and explainations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your loop :

- the `i` starts at `0`, so the first value is `0`
- it stops when `i<5` is not true, so when `i=5` it doesn't loop, so the last value is `4`

---

So `i`will take the values:

```
i -> action
0 -> go into else : result +=  0 so result is 0
1 -> go into else : result +=  1 so result is 1 
2 -> go into else : result +=  2 so result is 3
3 -> go into if   : result += 10 so result is 13
4 -> go into else : result +=  4 so result is 17
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop do for `i` starting to value 0

```
int i = 0
```

loop until `i` is greater than 4

```
i < 5;
```

and add 1 to `i` for each loop.

```
i++
```

then when `i` reach value 3

```
 if(i == 3){
```

add 10 to the `result` variable

```
result += 10;
```

if it's another value, add `i` value to `result`

```
 }else{
        result += i;
```

**the reason the result is 17 is :**

first loop, `i` = 0 and is not 3 so you add `i` to `result` : `result` = 0

then on second loop `i` = 1 and is not 3 so you add `i` to `result` : `result` = 0 + 1

then on third loop `i` = 2 and is not 3 so you add `i` to `result` : `result` = 1 + 2

then on fourth loop `i` = 3 **and it is 3 so you add 10** to `result` : `result` = 3 + 10

then on 5th loop `i` = 4 and is not 3 so you add `i` to `result` : **`result` = 13 + 4 = 17**

there is no 6th loop because `i` is no longer smaller than 5

Answer (score 1):

Here code explanation given below line by line:

```
int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){ 
if(i == 3)
{ 
  result += 10;
}
else{
  result += i;
}
}
System.out.println(result);
```

**Line 1:** Result variable (type int) initialized to zero(0)

**Line 2:** We are using a for loop that will run from 0 to 4 (5 times)

**Line 3-6 (if-condition):** We are using if-condition here, If i == 3 then it will add 10 to result variable else (when i is not equal to 3) it will add value of i to result variable.

For i equals to 0, 1, 2 and 4 it will add value of i to result(else part) and for i equals to 3 it will add 10 to the value of result.

**Line 7:** At the end, We are displaying the value of result.

Comment: Thank you I now got it. I just was confused on how it was looping

Comment: I wish I could accept all answers here, you were all so helpfull +1 to you

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple commented version of your code:

```
//Result is set to 0 first
int result = 0;

//Basic for loop, int i = 0 is setting your counter to 0, 
//then i < 5 is the loop's stop condtion
//Finally i++ represent the incrementation, in this case "i++" means i = i + 1
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

//Here if i = 3 result  = result + 10
    if(i == 3){ 
        result += 10;

// Else you add i's value to your result
    }else{
        result += i;
    }
}
//I = 5 so you get out of the loop
//In the end you print the result
System.out.println(result);
```

result's value:

```
i = 0 -> result(0) + 0 -> 0
i = 1 -> result(0) + 1 -> 1
i = 2 -> result(1) + 2 -> 3
i = 3 -> result(3) + 10 -> 13
i = 4 -> result(13) + 4 -> 17
i = 5 -> you get out of the loop
Final result : result = 17
```

Answer (score 1):

`for` loop initializes variable `i` to `0` and in each iteration adds 1 to it. So in first iteration `i` is `0`, in the next iteration, `i` is `1` and so on. In each iteration, the body of the loop, i.e., the code under the `for` statement is executed.
Let's now look at the body of the loop. In the body, it is examining whether `i` takes up the value `3` (`i==3`). When `i` takes up the value 3 (i.e., in the 4th iteration), `10` gets added to the result. (`result += 10` is the same as `result=result+10`. The else condition is excuted whenever `i` takes up **any value other than 3**.
So when `i` is 0, 1 or 2,  the value of `result` respectively will be
0 (0+0), 1 (O+1), 3 (1+2).
When `i=3`, result = result + 10  **->** result = 3 + 10 **->** result = 13
When `i=4`, result = result + i **->** result = 13+4 **->** result = 17
`i` cannot take up value 5 since it won't agree with the condition `i<5`. Hence you have
**result = 17**

Comment: Yeah, I was missing to add 1 + 3 to 10 then  add 4. Thank you alot

Answer (score 1):

The operation `result += 10` is not result is 10.
You can also write it like this: result=result+10 which is easy to understand. `+=` is shorthand notation.
`i<5` loop will return 0-4. we know only (i==3) have increment of +10.

First loop: `0`;

Second loop: `0(result)+1(i)=1`

Third loop: `1+2=3`

4th: `3+10=13`

5th: `13+4=17`